# Flash actionscript 2 remove linkage MovieClip

Tags: flash, random, actionscript-2, movieclip

I'm making a banner and in the banner I have a movie-clip that link from the library in action script and call "mcHelmet". I need it to appear in a randomly position on the x axis and it move from top to bottom  (like rain).

The problem is that after 25 sec' I want that it will go to another frame (10) 
and the "mcHelmet" will disappear.
All works fine except that the "mcHelmet" refuses to disappear no matter what code I use;
delete , remoceMovieClip,  using a function  nothing works.

I need help.

This is the code I use:

```
onEnterFrame = function (){
url_btn.onRollOver = btn.onDragOver = function (){
        startDrag(mc_girl,true,10,186,270,131);
        mc_girl._x = _xmouse;

        if(_xmouse < mc_girl.width /2){
            mc_girl._x = 0;
        }

        if(_xmouse > stage.width - mc_girl.width /2){
            mc_girl._x =Stage.width - mc_girl._width;
        }
        if(mc_girl._x <= 0){
            mc_girl._x += mainSpeed;
        }
        if(mc_girl._x >= Stage.width - mc_girl._width){
            mc_girl._x -= mainSpeed;
        }

        StopTimer();
    }

//this function will run every frame (needed for moving the character
HelmetTime++;
//incrementing time for enemy
if (HelmetTime == HelmetLimit)
{
    //if enough time has elapsed
    _root.attachMovie('mcHelmet','en' + HelmetTotal,_root.getNextHighestDepth());
    //then add the enemy
    //setting it's coordinates
    _root['en' + HelmetTotal]._x = int(Math.random() * Stage.width);
    //randomly within the boundaries
    _root['en' + HelmetTotal]._y = -50;
    //sets this offstage at first
    _root['en' + HelmetTotal].onEnterFrame = function()
    {
        //then give it some functions
        this._y += 4;
    }
    HelmetTime = 0;
    //reset the time
    HelmetTotal++;
    //add 1 more to the amount of enemies total

}
}
```

Comment: I think in AS2 you could only remove the most recent MC you added, and I think it was called something like detachMovie or something like that. If you search for Flash API Actionscript 2 you should find the reference.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the last mc you haved put on the stage, i suggest a variable or an array;Array would be efficient enough :

```
            var myMovieclips_holder:Array = new Array();
            //everytime you add a mc to stage ,also add it here 
            addchild(myMovieClip)
            myMovieclips.push(myMovieClip);
```

now your MovieClips will be stored in the array();

```
             trace( myMovieclips_holder) // array[0] Movie clip , array[1] etc
```

lets remove the last clip  :

```
              var  i = myMovieclips_holder.length - 1
              myMovieclips_holder[i].parent.removeChild(myMovieclips_holder[i]);
```

This should delete the last item from your array nomatter where you have nested it
worked for me.

Comment: thanks. i will try it and let you know 
the problem that i'm not so control in AS2 professionally so i hope i will do it right.